# What conditional should I use in PHP to check if JSON data from my AJAX request was successfully received?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, conditional-statements

I have a PHP script that outputs an HTML input field and a button. When the user inputs something then submits it an AJAX call posts to the server with the input field value. Then an email is sent.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));   
if(!empty($data)){
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  sendEmail($mail, $data->email);
}else{
  echo "<input id=\"SSB_input_email\" type=\"email\" name=\"email\" placeholder=\"Email\" required>
  <button id=\"SSB_DomainRegBtn\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"domainReg()\">Submit</button>";
}

//Define PHPMailer sendEmail
function sendEmail($param, $param01){
        try {
             //$param01 is the user email address
             //etc
...
```

Then on the clientside

```
let domainReg = ()=>{
var emailReg = document.getElementById("SSB_input_email").value;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   //modifies DOM here   
   }
  };
   xhr.open("POST", "../onlineStoreBackend/index.php", true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   var data = {email: emailReg};
   xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
   }
```

I can't seem to get the conditional to evaluate to true on the server code when the AJAX call is sent. I've also tried

```
 if(isset($data->email)){...
```

That doesn't work either, what am I doing wrong here?
BTW the PHPmailer function is not the problem as I've tested it by explicitly setting the conditional to true so that an email is sent as soon as the page loads and this works, but that's obviously not the functionality I need here

Comment: You should start by verifying `$data` contains the values you expect it to

Comment: var_dump ($data) returns expected results and passing $data->email as the second argument to the sendEmail function when the conditional is explicitly set to true verifies that the data from the client is successfully being posted

Comment: Don't use param0, param1 etc, give meaningful names to variables.

Comment: They are parameters, and also semantically unrelated to my question

Comment: I've tested it the code works with if(!empty($data)){.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll do some more tests